# Is there any function called when I press on an tabber item (at the bottom) on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Say I have a tabber item a that displays a view v1, now I push sv1 while viewing v1. If I press the tabber icon at the bottom, then I have seen that it takes me back to view v1. Is it the default behavior? Is there any function called when I press tabbar item on iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a UITabBarController if you're using a UITabBar. It has delegate methods to inform you when selection changes, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented the `UITabBarDelegate`, you can can check the `-tabBar:didSelectItem` function.

Check the documentation on Apple's site for the details.